# React function does not await data from Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Everytime I run the following code React seems to continue and not fill the CurrentDevice as I asked in setCurrentDevice. It just throws an undefined in the log when asked on the last line. It does seem to log the correct device details as I can see when the first console.log runs. How do I make react fill the state CurrentDevice before continuing?

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'DeviceDetails'), where('serialNo', '==', SerialNo))

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      setCurrentDevice(doc.data());
      console.log(doc.data());
    })

    console.log(currentDevice);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you update a `hook` as `useState` in this example the `component`  re-render with the new `value` of the `hook` so `currentDevice` will get the new `value` during the next render it's not available yet. try to `consol.log('this is a new render and this is my data : ',currentDevice)` from inside your `jsx` to understand better.

**note also**, that here with your code, you are only storing the last `item` of `querySnapshot` inside your `currentDevice` not all the `items` because on every itteration you are overwritting the value so it will end only with the last one, I don't know what you are trying to do but I don't think this is what you want to achieve, if you want to store them all, this is the right way

```js
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
setCurrentDevice(querySnapshot.map((doc) => doc.data()));
```

but if you really want to store only the last `item` better to do it like this :

```js
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
setCurrentDevice(querySnapshot[querySnapshot.length- 1].data());
```

Comment: The thing is, I need the currentDevice a few lines below to check if currentDevice has the same details as details entered in a form. So is there any way to make it wait so I can preform that check?

Comment: so you compare with `doc.data()`

Comment: that is correct yes. I thought this was the way to go for now because I use the details of this document later to send an email about the details of the device.

Comment: so do you think if I directly compare with doc.data() instead of putting it in a state, it will solve my issue of the state not being filled

Comment: you fill the state to be updated during the next render but you compare with `doc.data()`

Comment: My apologies for the late response, I asked this question at the end of my shift yesterday and only started again now. It did work thank you!

Comment: note I also updated my answer for more informations